# Deriving Data for a record with functions

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

I am ultimately trying to define nested records of functions which I want to traverse generically in order to replace on deeply nested function.

Something like this

```
data Module1 = Module1 {
  _module2 :: Module2
  _function1 :: Int -> String
} deriving (Typeable)

data Module2 = Module2 {
  _module3 :: Module3
  _function2 :: Double -> String
} deriving (Typeable)

data Module3 = Module3 {
  _function3 :: Float -> String
} deriving (Typeable)

replace :: (Float -> String) -> Module1 -> Module1
replace = undefined
```

I want to implement replace so that `_function3` is replaced in the `Module1` data structure. I am trying to implement this by defining `Data` instances for `Module 1, 2, 3` but I am currently failing to understand / implement `gunfold` and associated methods on `Data`.

Question 1: how do you implement a `Data` instance for such data types?
Question 2: can I achieve my goal and implement `replace` with such instances?

Comment: `Data` instances are usually derived (`deriving Data`), not written by hand. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this an exercise in generic programming, because I would just use the [lens library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

Comment: I was hoping my first sentence and the definition of the `replace` function would explain my intentions well enough :-). I want to be able to recurse into the `ModuleN` structure (without having to describe the full path using a lens) until I find a function of a given type to replace it.

Comment: @dfeuer `deriving Data` fails here because there are no instances for functions

Comment: If you want to define `Data` instances for these types, you'll need a `Data` instance for functions. You can define such an instance in the same way the `Data (Ptr a)` instance is defined, for example. However this problem is much better suited for `GHC.Generics` (which doesn't care if your type contains non-representable types). (Note: "I am currently failing to understand / implement gunfold and associated methods on Data" isn't really an on-topic question)

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at all of that.